# How to represent an xml element inside the text part of parent element with JSON

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a JSON representation of some data for web API response. e.g. the XML representation of the data will look like

```xml
<parent>
    parent text <child>child text</child> more parent text
</parent>
```

can somebody tell me the correct representation of this XML in JSON? or any suggestions? The child element may not always exist but, when it does, its location has to be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious way to represent that as JSON. There is no direct equivalents in JSON to text nodes and elements in XML.

One way could be to use strings as the closest thing to text nodes in XML, but that gives you an array with mixed data types, which might not be as easy to parse. Example:

```
[
  "parent text ",
  { "text": "child text" },
  " more parent text"
]
```

Another way could be to use an array of objects, where each object has a type and a text. You could use a type `"text"` to represent plain text and a type `"child"` to represent a child element:

```
[
  { "type": "text", "text": "parents text " }
  { "type": "child", "text": "child text" }
  { "type": "text", "text": " more parent text" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that was one of the options we had but it will leave the user to find all the text types and concatenate, just to get the text value of the parent. But still we are leaning towards this option

Comment: What do you think of keeping the whole text together and keep the offset in the child element.

Comment: @Fisseha: Yes, if easily getting the whole text content of the parent is a priority, that would be an option. It would not be as human readable though.

Comment: well I guess your suggestion is the best we can find so we decided on applying that and let the client code collect the text values when needed. Thanks so much

Comment: Both are kinda the same solution which is splitting into different objects/text. I wish I could mark both as answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any clean, human-readable way to represent this in JSON, but you could consider each node as a list of children nodes. If it's a plain text node, represent it as a string, otherwise, make it an object.

Client code will then have to check the type of each value (if it's a string or object).

Something like this:

```
{
    "parent":
        [
            "parent text ",
            {
                "child": [
                    "child text"
                ],
            }
            " more parent text"
        ]
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, that was one of the reason I was hoping to see if there is a different approach than expecting clients to find all text types and concatenate.

Comment: an other option was just to keep the offset.                                     "parent": {
    "Text": "parent text more parent text",
    "child": [
      {
        "Text": "child text",       
        "Offset": 13
      }
    ]